# Passing a return Json result into a Dictionary

Tags: c#, json

I have got this:

```
UserModel um = new UserModel();
var aux = um.get_OPTLM_Users();
return Json(aux.users.Select(u => new UserModel { Name = u.user.name, Id = u.user.id }).Distinct(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Which returns nicely into the View, with pairs of id-value that fill a combobox nicely. But I need to store that query result into a dictionary. I have tried the following:

```
var aux2 = Json(aux.users.Select(u => new UserModel { Name = u.user.name, Id = u.user.id }).Distinct(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

It stores into the `aux2` variable what I think is a JsonResult variable but I can't access the data in it.

[image: print]

How can I pass the contents into a dictionary?

Comment: What happens if you expand the Results View?

Comment: I can't, there's no option to do that

Comment: Click the refresh button to the left of "Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable"

Comment: @DoctorMick: `Results View = 'System.Linq.Enumerable.DistinctIterator<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<TSource>)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'`

Comment: A dictionary with what keys and values?  Do you want to return the dictionary, or cache it locally?

Comment: @dbc, I just want to fill it, not return it. The keys-values are the query result, you can see in the code: Name and Id -> `Name = u.user.name, Id = u.user.id`